# Tricep extensions, stand up or lie down?

Tags: weightlifting, triceps

When performing tricep extensions, is it better to be lying flat on a bench or standing upright?

Is there pros / cons that support either case?

I usually perform them with both hands simultaneously, holding a plate, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

This question is primarily opinion based, so, I’ll answer it in that context.

When it comes to triceps development, I’m a firm believer in attacking all [three heads](http://www.ironmanmag.com.au/training/training-tips/417-triceps-how-to-train-all-three-heads) of the muscle since triceps make up the bulk of the upper arm.  For me, that means using many different types of exercises **and** different angles (flat and standing).  While using a plate is an option, I don’t think it is sufficient if that’s all you do.  If available, I would suggest you use a combination of dumbbell, barbell (e-z bar), and cable exercises to ensure you train all three heads.

Comment: If you think it's opinion based, downvote / vote to close it, don't answer a question you think is off-topic.

Comment: And according to your link, standing overhead extensions target more areas of the tricep than lying down. So the answer to my question is **it's better to be standing up**.

Comment: No problem.  The purpose of that link was to stress exercising all three heads.  It was not to recommend lying flat or standing.  And, the article does not explicitly state "standing".  It only refers to "overhead" which can be also performed lying down.

Comment: Same link as my answer. +1 for better explanation though

Answer (score -1):

It really depends what you're going for. They will each work the tricep a bit differently.

There's an article [here](http://www.ironmanmag.com.au/training/training-tips/417-triceps-how-to-train-all-three-heads) on what you can do for the different heads.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but it's pretty poor. _It all depends... read this article_. That's not very helpful. Links have a tendency to die over time and it's bad practice to answer a question with a link alone.

Comment: hmmm, Fair enough.

Comment: Just to be a little nicer than @Daft - on the SE Model its preferred for users to summarize the important parts of links so that if, as Daft mentions, the link dies this answer will still be useful.